# Why is my gatsby site deployed with a path prefix requesting for a non-existent file when my url does not end with a trailing slash

Tags: url, gatsby

I have deployed a Gatsby site with gitlab-ci and aws cloudfront both with and without a path prefix.

The **non-prefixed** site requests for correct files and displays them correctly in my browser no matter if I put a trailing slash at the end of the url or not.

However, for the **prefixed** site, it requests for files that do not exist in my `public/` directory when I don't put a trailing slash at the end of the url (i.e. [www.example.com/path-prefix](http://www.example.com/path-prefix) does not work properly). Everything works properly if I put a trailing slash at the end of the url (i.e. [www.example.com/path-prefix/](http://www.example.com/path-prefix/) works). I also noticed that the site without a trail slash is requesting for similar files but the names of the files are incorrect. For example, if [www.example.com/path-prefix/](http://www.example.com/path-prefix/) is requesting for `example-abcdefg123456.js`, which is auto-generated during the build process, then [www.example.com/path-prefix](http://www.example.com/path-prefix) is requesting for `example-aslkfdjaskdfh234.js` which does not exist in the `public/` directory.

Besides, for the site other than the homepage, the above phenomenon does not exist. For example, both [www.example.com/path-prefix/blog](http://www.example.com/path-prefix/blog) and [www.example.com/path-prefix/blog/](http://www.example.com/path-prefix/blog/) work correctly as gatsby always auto appends a trailing slash to the url that does not end with a slash.

I also noticed that sometime of the day, gatsby would auto append a trailing slash to the homepage as well so that [www.example.com/path-prefix](http://www.example.com/path-prefix) always becomes [www.example.com/path-prefix/](http://www.example.com/path-prefix/). Hence, the above bug will disappear automatically.

Has anyone ever encountered this weird error before or maybe know how to debug for this problem?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure perhaps this plugin might be of interest https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes/

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at that one